# Adding Windows 7 VM as a log source/forcing the IDS inline

Tags: ids, snort

I'm investigating ways to add my Windows 7 VM as a log source or even run that traffic through my IDS VM and then out to the internet but I'm not entirely sure how to approach it.

Does anybody have any suggestions?  I had the stupid idea of setting the gateway on the Windows 7 VM to the IDS VM and then using iptables to forward everything to the router whilst monitoring whatever passes through but that seems incredibly long winded.